# How to create a transparent component inherited from TCustomControl?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I would like to paint a semi-transparent rectangle that would cover the entire father, where it should overlap all the visual components.

I can't use `TCustomTransparentControl`.

Component code:

```
unit CustomTransparente;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.NetEncoding,
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.D2D1,
  Winapi.Messages,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Direct2D,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.Forms;

type
  TCustomTransparente = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FColor         : TColor;
    FTitleLabel    : TLabel;
    procedure InitialComponent(ATitle : String);
    procedure CreateTitle(ATitle : String);
  protected
    procedure WMWindowPosChanging(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanging); message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; ATitle : String); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  published
  end;

implementation

{ TCustomTransparente }

constructor TCustomTransparente.Create(AOwner: TComponent; ATitle : String);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  DoubleBuffered         := True;
  ControlStyle           := ControlStyle + [csOpaque];
  FColor                 := clWhite;
  ParentBackground       := False;
  Width                  := TControl(AOwner).Width;
  Top                    := TControl(AOwner).Top ;
  Height                 := TControl(AOwner).Height;
  StyleElements          := [];
  InitialComponent(ATitle);
end;

procedure TCustomTransparente.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;

procedure TCustomTransparente.CreateTitle(ATitle : String);
begin
  if not Assigned(FTitleLabel) then
  begin
    FTitleLabel              := TLabel.Create(Self);
    FTitleLabel.Parent       := Self;
    FTitleLabel.Font.Name    := 'Tahoma';
    FTitleLabel.Font.Size    := 10;
    FTitleLabel.Caption      := ATitle;
    FTitleLabel.Left         := (Width) div 2;
    FTitleLabel.Top          := (Height) div 2;
    FTitleLabel.Height       := 20;
    FTitleLabel.Color        := clBtnFace;
    FTitleLabel.Transparent  := True;
    FTitleLabel.Font.Color   := clBlack;
    FTitleLabel.Font.Quality := fqClearType;
    FTitleLabel.AutoSize     := False;
    FTitleLabel.Alignment    := taCenter;
  end;
end;

destructor TCustomTransparente.Destroy;
begin
  FTitleLabel.Free;
  inherited;
end;


procedure TCustomTransparente.InitialComponent(ATitle : String);
begin
  CreateTitle(ATitle);
end;

procedure TCustomTransparente.Paint;
var
  LRoundRect       : TD2D1RoundedRect;
  RectF            : TD2D1RectF;
  SolidColorBrush  : ID2D1SolidColorBrush;
  ColorF           : TD2D1ColorF;
  LCanvas          : TDirect2DCanvas;
begin
  LCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Canvas, ClientRect);
  LCanvas.BeginDraw;
  try
    RectF.left   := 1;
    RectF.top    := 1;
    RectF.right  := Width-2;
    RectF.bottom := Height-2;

    LRoundRect.rect    := RectF;
    LRoundRect.radiusX := 16;
    LRoundRect.radiusY := 16;

    ColorF.r := GetRValue(FColor) / 255;
    ColorF.g := GetGValue(FColor) / 255;
    ColorF.b := GetBValue(FColor) / 255;
    ColorF.a := 0.7;

    LCanvas.RenderTarget.CreateSolidColorBrush(ColorF, nil, SolidColorBrush);
    LCanvas.Pen.Width := 1;

    LCanvas.RenderTarget.FillRoundedRectangle(LRoundRect, SolidColorBrush);
  finally
    LCanvas.EndDraw;
    LCanvas.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomTransparente.WMWindowPosChanging(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanging);
begin
  inherited;
  BringToFront;
  with Message.WindowPos^ do
    flags := flags or SWP_NOZORDER;
end;

end.
```

```
unit uMessageCustom;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Controls,
  CustomTransparente,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs;


type
  TMessageCustom = class(TComponent)
  private
    FCustomTransparente: TCustomTransparente;
    FOwner        : TWinControl;
  public
    procedure Show(pParent: TWinControl; const pTitle : string);
    procedure Hide;
  end;


procedure Register;

implementation

procedure TMessageCustom.Hide;
begin
  if Assigned(FCustomTransparente) then
  begin
    FOwner.Enabled := True;
    FCustomTransparente.Free;
    FCustomTransparente := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TMessageCustom.Show(pParent: TWinControl; const pTitle : string);
begin
  FCustomTransparente           := TCustomTransparente.Create(pParent, pTitle);
  FCustomTransparente.Parent    := pParent;
  FOwner                        := pParent;
  FOwner.Enabled                := False;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
 RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMessageCustom]);
end;

end.
```

Form:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, CustomTransparente, Vcl.StdCtrls, uMessageCustom;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MessageCustom1: TMessageCustom;
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MessageCustom1.Show(Panel1, 'Hello World');
end;

end.
```

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 313
  ClientWidth = 578
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 248
    Top = 280
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 577
    Height = 274
    Color = clWhite
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 1
    object Edit1: TEdit
      Left = 272
      Top = 127
      Width = 121
      Height = 21
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'Edit1'
    end
  end
  object MessageCustom1: TMessageCustom
    Left = 504
    Top = 24
  end
end
```

Below is the image, my component is behind Edit

[image]

I tried `ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csOpaque];` unsuccessfully.

Comment: Did you try create the window with the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style activated. AFAIK otherwise the control clips the background drawing. WM_ERASEBKGND is to catch too. And then you would need to combine your own drawing with an alpha channel e.g. create a bitmap draw your stuff then draw that bitmap on top of the canvase with an alpha value...
This link might be of help: https://tips.delphidabbler.com/tips/74

Comment: Style with `+ [csOpaque]` is never going to be **transparent**. It will be **opaque**. Please edit your question and provide [mcve]. We need complete, but minimal example that shows the issue, so we can easily read the code without having to go through a lot of code unrelated to the issue, but at the same time it needs to have all relevant parts included so that we can reproduce the behavior if needed. That means complete code required for your component to work and paint it self, not just the paint method. Transparency depends on the many parts and we need to see them all.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I provided a simple example code

Comment: Would it be enough for this custom message of yours to have fixed transparency across entire control or do you require some parts of the control to have higher transparency than the other parts. If it is the former then I suggest that instead of creating new control you just create a new borderless form and simply set it's [AlphaBlendValue](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.AlphaBlendValue). And as long as you set your form parent property to some other control it will be rendered within that control. ...

Comment: ... Or in case if you have installed source code  samples with your Delphi you might be able to copy the code from TFoorm class tzhat provides forms with Alpha Blend functionality to your custom control.

Comment: @SilverWarior every control can be semi-transparent. But in this case of AlphaBlend, every component I enter in this form will also be transparent and it is not ideal